# Python max() not working? Not actually giving me the maximum

Tags: python, list, max

Having a problem recently when using the max() function in python. Here is my code:

```
x = ["AJK","exit","Down","World","HappyASD"]
max(x)
```

But instead of getting "HappyASD", I get "exit".
Any help?

Comment: How are you defining maximum? Longest string?

Comment: `max` compares lexicographically, the value of `e` is higher than `H`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34115735/4099593) answer to know how `max` works on lists

Comment: I wonder if OP is simply looking for `x[-1]`.

Comment: Please clarify how _you_ are defining "maximum".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for the max by length, you need to [send the key to the `max` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

```
x = ["AJK","exit","Down","World","HappyASD"]
max(x, key=len)
```

DEMO:

```
>>> x = ["AJK","exit","Down","World","HappyASD"]
>>> max(x, key=len)
'HappyASD'
>>>
```

If the key is not specified, by default the max is determined by the coerced type.

Comment: I tried this and it works! Thanks, didn't realise you need to pass anything into the max() function (this is why I hate python). Going to mark this as correct.

Comment: @AlexKnight: How do you expect Python to know that you want maximum by string length rather than its default ordering unless you tell it?

Comment: @AlexKnight i understand your frustration. Just give it some more time and you will start appreciate the flexibility and simplicity that Python provides.. It is the initial phases you might have a few hiccups with. But trust me, you will like it over time.

Comment: "This is why I hate python", WUT??!? You should know the tools you want to use. You won't expect a car to tell you how to drive it right?

Comment: @karthikr I know, it's just I have been dabbling with C++, so naturally compare python. So that's why I get frustrated sometimes, but I would always recommend python for its simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

ord('e')=101 is higher than ord('H')=72

Answer (score 0):

can see no error in here... ord values of first letter in `exit` are the highest

Answer (score 0):

It is because the max() compares the ascii value of the character. I think.
'e' is 0x65, while, 'A' is 0x41, 'D' is 0x44 and so on.

you can refer to:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_max.htm