# How to print min of set in python?

Tags: python, set, min

I have a set

```
ww = [{27, 29, 6, 71}, {75, 52, 29, 46, 7}, {20, 71}, {59}, {52, 37, 15}]
```

and I want to print the element that has the shortest length ie. {59} in this example.

```
min(ww)
```

would only give me {27, 29, 6, 71} instead of {59}

is there a way of using min() to do this? or any other smart methods?

Comment: Set the key to length

Comment: Use `min(ww, key=len)`. Lists are sorted lexicographically, So you need to specify the key, See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050113/how-does-the-min-max-function-on-a-nested-list-work/34115735#34115735

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
In [3]: min(ww,key=len)
Out[3]: {59}
```

Or

```
In [4]: sorted(ww,key=len)[0]
Out[4]: {59}
```

Comment: Why would you ever use an O(n log n) approach ? Even to get the k shortest length sub-elements there are better approaches.