# Python: Minimum of lists using custom function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If I create a list of tuples `lst = [(0,5), (5,0), (2,2)]` and use `min(lst)`, it returns `(0,5)`.

How does python decide which tuple to be the smallest?

Is it using first element of tuple to make a decision?

How should I change it to return minimum sum of tuple assuming there are only 2 elements in tuples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the min/max function on a nested list work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050113/how-does-the-min-max-function-on-a-nested-list-work)

Comment: @YoungBinJo, if one of the below solutions helped, consider accepting it (green tick on left) so other users know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom key with `min`.

```
lst = [(0,5), (5,0), (2,2)]

res = min(lst, key=lambda x: sum(x))
# (2, 2)
```

To understand how `min(lst)` works in general, see [How does the min/max function on a nested list work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050113/how-does-the-min-max-function-on-a-nested-list-work)

If you wish to retrieve element with minimum sum sorted by first element, you can specify a tuple key:

```
lst2 = [(0,5), (5,0), (2,2), (1,3)]

res = min(lst2, key=lambda x: (sum(x), x[0]))
# (1, 3)
```

Without using the tuple key, the result above would be `(2,2)`.

Comment: also, first and third element have different sums (5 versus 4).